# What if your fact has multiple instances of the dimension?

Tags: sql, data-warehouse, star-schema

In a star schema for a clothes shop, there is a transaction fact to capture everything bought.  This will usually have the usual date, time, amount dimensions but it will also have a person to indicate who bought it. In certain cases you can have multiple people on the same transaction.  How is that modelled if the foreign key is on the Fact table and hence can only point to one Person?

Answer (score 3):

The standard technique in dimensional modelling is to use a 'Bridge' table.
The classic examples you'll find are groups of customers having accounts (or transactions), and for patients having multiple diagnoses when visiting a hospital.

In your case this might look like:

Table: *`FactTransaction`*

- `PersonGroupKey`
- Other FactTableColumns

Table: *`BridgePersonGroup`*

- `PersonGroupKey`
- `PersonKey`

Table: *`DimPerson`*

- `PersonKey`
- Other person columns

For each group of people you'd create a new PersonGroupKey and end up with rows like this:

```
PersonGroupKey 1, PersonKey 5
PersonGroupKey 1, PersonKey 3
PersonGroupKey 2, PersonKey 1
PersonGroupKey 3, PersonKey 6
```

PersonGroupKey then represents the group of people in the Fact.

Logically speaking, there should be a further table, DimPersonGroup, which just lists the PersonGroupKeys, but most databases don't require this so typically Kimball modellers do away with it.

That's the basics of the Bridge table, but you might consider modifications depending on your situation!

Comment: Beside the naming, how is that different from the answer I posted previously?

Comment: Your answer yesterday had a transaction Id in the bridge table. I thought it worth posting my own answer rather than needing you to edit yours

Comment: Fair enough, you deserve the upvote ;-) I got a downvote on mine after correcting it, not too sure why

Answer (score 1):

You need a joining table `TransactionPerson` (or something like that), where `Person` to `TransactionPerson` is 1:M relationship and then `TransactionPerson` to `Transaction` is M:1 relationship.

That way you can have multiple people relating to one transaction indirectly.

Comment: That makes sense. Do you have a link which shows this approach and usually the stuff I find doesn't have joining tables between the facts and dimensions.

Comment: @MoreThanFive Joining tables (also called mapping tables) are very common solution to normalizing many-to-many (M:M) relationship into two one-to-many (1:M) relationship. A biproduct of this normalization is an extra joining table. If you google how to normalize many-to-many, pretty much everything should point you to this approach.

Answer (score 1):

I would propose to use a Bridge table in combination with your transaction and person tables. Ex:

**Table: `fact_transaction`**

- `transaction_id` (primary key)
- `transaction_person_id` (foreign key)
- ...

**Table: `bridge_transaction_person`**

- `transaction_person_id`
- `person_id`

**Table: `dim_person`**

- `person_id` (primary key)
- ...

Comment: The standard Bridge table in dimensional modelling wouldn't rely on having information about the fact in the bridge table (i.e. there would be no transaction id). Instead, the bridge table would represent the group of people, and the fact table would have a foreign key to that.

Comment: @Rich ok maybe, I am not an expert on bridge tables, in this case I will remove my last comment and adjust the solution